# Remove a character from all rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data something like this:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~id,
  "a;"
  "b;"
  "c;"
)
```

How can I remove ";" from data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(id = str_remove(id, fixed(";")))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  id   
#  <chr>
#1 a    
#2 b    
#3 c
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R`

```
data$id <- sub(";", "", data$id, fixed = TRUE)
```